# How can fonts be loaded into a PDF document with PDFiumSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, pdfium

I'm trying to add a custom font (otf file or for testing purpose ttf) to my PDF document to render text page objects with. The rendered text is always the same gibberish like `ÿÿÿÿÿÿe` ('e' might be the last char of my string or a random character). Creating, rendering and adding other objects like paths or images are working fine. So I'm guessing the font isn't loaded correctly.

I'm using an updated version of the C# wrapper PDFiumSharp ( https://github.com/ArgusMagnus/PDFiumSharp ), which provides the following methods: `FPDFText_LoadFont(document, FontType, IsCid, byte[] fontData)` and `FPDFPageObj_CreateTextObj(document, FPDF_Font font, size)`. The wiki of PDFiumSharp states that through `LoadFont` the font is loaded into the document. The code snippet following runs through without problems (so fontpath is correct, can be loaded and the text object can be created).

I exchanged the pdfium.dll with the newest one from https://github.com/bblanchon/pdfium-binaries, which includes the entry point FPDF_LoadFont too.

There is also another entry point `FPDF_InitLibraryWithConfig`, which gets a `FPDF_LIBRARY_CONFIG` as argument. This config holds a readonly field `IntPtr _userFontPaths`, which might me usable somehow, but I haven't find a way to set this.

```cs
public void AddText(int pageIndex, string text, int posX, int posY, float scale, string fontPath)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fontPath)) return;

    // load default font, if not already loaded
    try
    {
        byte[] fontData = File.ReadAllBytes(fontPath);
        _font = PDFium.FPDFText_LoadFont(_document.Handle, FontTypes.TrueType, false, fontData);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return;
    }

    FPDF_PAGEOBJECT obj = PDFium.FPDFPageObj_CreateTextObj(_document.Handle,
                                                           _font,
                                                            12.0f * scale);

    /* Matrix: | a, c, e| ==> | width, 0,      offsetX|
     *         | b, d, f|     | 0,     height, offsetY|*/
    PDFium.FPDFPageObj_Transform(obj, 1, 0, 0, 1, posX, posY);

    PDFium.FPDFText_SetText(obj, text);

    PDFium.FPDFPage_InsertObject(_document.Pages[pageIndex].Handle, ref obj);
}
```

Calling it with:

```cs
AddText(0, "Hello Snape", 10, 50, 1, @"C:\SomeFont.ttf");
```

The rendered result in some PDF viewers is like this: `ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿe` or `(some spaces) e` (though you can not see the spaces of course) or empty. My expected result is `Hello Snape`. The transformation is okay, as the wrong texts are displayed at the wanted position.

Edit:
After updating the wrapper, so that `FPDFPageObj_CreateTextObj` takes the `FPDF_FONT` instead of the font name as string, the text is displayed with the correct font. The gibberish remains.(Updated code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the problem was again in the wrapper:
The function `bool FPDFText_SetText(FPDF_PAGEOBJECT text_object, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string text)` needed a `LPStr`. Changing it to `LPWStr` did the trick.